# TODOリストの値がクリアされない、ストップウォッチが表示されない

Tags: javascript, monaca, html, html5

お世話になります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Monacaで日々の運動記録を作ろうと思っています。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/samples/todo/

新規作成し、TODOリストを読み込みました。

そのまま携帯と連携して動作させたところ、
Addした後のデータがクリアされず、
前回の値が保持されたままになってしまっています。

これは、元の提供のデータがおかしいということでしょうか?

また、メモ帳とストップウォッチを使い
行った時間を記録していきたいと思っています。
http://www.red.oit-net.jp/tatsuya/java/stopw.htm

上記を参考に、HTMLに組み込んでも動きませんでした。

良い勉強サイト等ありませんか？

作ろうとしているものとしては、

TOPぺーじにA,Bの画像２つ、ボタン2つ
ボタンをおしたら、それぞれのHTML（A,B)に移動
A,Bそれぞれ、Aの画像とストップウォッチ、Bの画像とストップウォッチがある
（カウントダウン形式）
終わったら、リストに結果を保存

TOPページは作れます。
ボタンをおしたらそれぞれのHTMLに移動も可能（なはずです）
ストップウォッチの表示がどうにも上手く行きません。

Comment: データがクリアされない点については、お試しになったソースコードと合わせて記載すると回答が得られやすいかと思います。
(現在の記載状況だと、具体的な問題がなにか想像するのが難しく、回答できる方がかなり限られてしまうかもしれません。)

Comment: 前半の質問は、TODOを登録した後別のTODOを登録しようとすると、前回登録した内容がそのままフォームに残っているので、毎回クリアされるようにしたい、ということでしょうか。後半、「良い勉強サイト」と言われても難しいですが、ストップウォッチについてはあなたの書かれたHTMLやJavascriptのコードを記載していただくことで具体的なアドバイスが得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

MonacaのサンプルのToDo Appのことだと仮定します。
このサンプルはToDoをAddした後に値のクリアをしていないので値が残っています。
Addした後に値をクリアしたい場合は、自分でクリアする処理を実装しましょう。

ストップウォッチの件ですが、せめてソースを提示して頂けないと
何が原因で表示が上手くいっていないのか回答することができません。